# stop timer after interval time in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am using `.net compact framework 3.5` in visual studio 2008.

I have created  a timer tick event to perform a job.I want to call the timer only once and after that i need to disable the timer.Please see my below code

```
   int counter = 0;
        var timer = new Timer { Enabled = true, Interval = 10000 };
        timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            Cleanup();
        };
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 1)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
        }
```

I tried with `timer.Enabled = false;` without any condition,what happens is the `Cleanup()` function is not calling which is inside the tick event.So from google i got one more solution to use a counter.With counter also i am facing the same problem,`Cleanup()` is not calling.

If i am not disable the timer,then the function is calling in every 10secs time.I need to call the `Cleanup()` function only once,which is inside the timer.tick.Need help to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: counter++; should be included in delegate, otherwise it's called immediately.

Comment: counter++; should be in the tick delagate

Comment: Take a look at this solution, you can use it for your case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814232/timer-event-to-increase-the-value-of-a-variable

Comment: Can you please specify which `Timer` class you are using. Clearly not `System.Threading.Timer`, possibly [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.Timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) based on `Tick` method...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It is not System.Threading.Timer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need a counter:

This should be enough

```
timer.Tick += delegate
{
   timer.Enabled = false;
   Cleanup();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach if you are using `System.Timers.Timer` - use [Timer.AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make it fire only once:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000) { AutoReset = false };
timer.Elapsed += (s,e)=>Cleanup();
timer.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Short notation using lambda:

```
var timer = new Timer { Enabled = true, Interval = 10000 };
timer.Tick +=()=>{ timer.Enabled=false; Cleanup();};
```